# How can I manually remove a specific ticklabel?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

In the following plot I would like to get rid of one specific ticklabel:

[image: a plot of the sigmoid function with an ugly label overlapping the x-axis]

Here is the code to generate the image:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-6, 6, 600)
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
y = sigmoid(x)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,3), dpi=300)

# Move left y-axis and bottom x-axis to centre, passing through (0,0)
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')

# Eliminate upper and right axes
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')

# Show ticks in the left and lower axes only
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

# Set axis range
ax.set_xlim(-6, 6)
# ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)

# Set axis labels
ax.set_xlabel(r"$x$", loc='right')
ax.set_ylabel(r"sigmoid$(x)$", loc='top')

# Set axes facecolor
ax.set_facecolor('none')

print(ax.get_yticklabels())
ax.plot(x,y)
print(ax.get_yticklabels())

plt.show()
```

I then get the following yticklabels before `plt.plot(x,y)`:

```
[Text(0, 0.0, '0.0'), Text(0, 0.2, '0.2'), Text(0, 0.4, '0.4'), Text(0, 0.6000000000000001, '0.6'), Text(0, 0.8, '0.8'), Text(0, 1.0, '1.0')]
```

And these after `plt.plot(x,y)`

```
[Text(0, -0.2, '−0.2'), Text(0, 0.0, '0.0'), Text(0, 0.2, '0.2'), Text(0, 0.4000000000000001, '0.4'), Text(0, 0.6000000000000001, '0.6'), Text(0, 0.8, '0.8'), Text(0, 1.0000000000000002, '1.0'), Text(0, 1.2000000000000002, '1.2')
```

My idea was to alter the labels using code like this:

```
ylabels = ax.get_yticklabels()
for lbl in ylabels:
    lbl_txt = lbl.get_text().replace('−', '-') # replace U+2212 with normal '-' (U+002d)
    if float(lbl_txt) == 0.:
        lbl.set_text('')
ylabels = ax.get_yticklabels()
ax.set_yticklabels(ylabels)
```

But and the code successfully replaces the '0.0' label with an empty string, but the figure looks the same. Also why are there two more yticklabels returned than there are shown in the figure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the explicit ticks you want:

```py
ax.set_yticks([.2, .4, .6, .8, 1.0])
ax.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One option:

```
for tl in ax.get_yticklabels():
    if tl.get_text() == '0.0':  # or   if tl.get_text() in {'0.0'}:
        tl.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

Another one:

```
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0.2, 1.1, 0.2))

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use your custom [formatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html):

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

formatter = lambda x, pos: '' if np.isclose(x, 0) else np.round(x, 1)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

**Update**: you can also simply use `ax.set_ylim(ymin=1e-9)`.

Output:

[image]